# Custom principal and scopes using Spring OAuth 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using SpringBoot 2.0.5 and Spring Security OAuth to implement an OAuth 2.0 server and a set of client microservices.

**In the AuthServer:**

1. I have implemented the `UserDetailsService` so I can provide my custom enriched principal.
2. For the `userInfoUri` controller endpoint, I return user (my principal) and authorities as a map.

**In the Client:**

1. I have implemented `PrincipalExtractor` to extract and create my custom principal.
2. For each of the methods I require the principal, I use the following notation:

   `public List<Message> listMessages(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyPrincipal user)`

This works (and I hope it's the right way) but now I'm having an issue to secure methods using scopes.

For example, if I want to have a controller method which is only accessible by another server (using client_credentials), I mark the method with the following annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('trust')")
```

But this results in an access error as I think the scope is not being transferred. I have added the scope to the `userInfoUri` endpoint but am unsure what I need to do on the client side so the scope is picked up.

Any pointers or example code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've temporarily got round this by removing the principal extractor and creating a class which implements `ResourceServerTokenServices` and adding the scope to the `OAuth2Request`. Seems a bit long winded, would like to know if there is an easier way to do this?